# Converting data to matrix by group in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to create matrix for each observation in my dataset.
Each row should correspond to disease group (i.e. xx, yy, kk). Example data

```
id  xx_z xx_y xx_a yy_b yy_c kk_t kk_r kk_m kk_y
1    1    1    0    0     1   0     0    1   1
2    0    0    1    0     0   1     1    0   1
```

Given that there are 3 types of diseases and there are maximum of 4 diseases in the dataset. The matrix should be by 3 X 4, and the output should look like:

```
       id       matrix           
              xx_z xx_y  xx_a null 
        1   xx [ 1    1    0    0 
               yy_b  yy_c  null null
            yy   0    1    0    0
                kk_t kk_r kk_k  kk_y
            kk   0    0    1    1]

      2       [ 0 0 1 0
              0 0 0 0
              1 1 0 1]
```

Please note that I do not know the exact number disease per disease group.  How could I do it in python pandas?

P.S. I just need a nested matrix structure for each observation, later I will compare the matrices of different observations, e.g. Jaccard similarity of matrices for observation id == 1 and observation id == 2

Comment: Could you put a matrix where you want the xx_z etc go?  I cannot work out from your description how to arrange the numbers in the top code block into the ones in the bottom code block

Comment: Sure let me do it

Comment: Where does kk_m go?  is it simply that the first xx goes to the first item etc...

Comment: Yes, exactly. I actually would like to calculate disease similarity of different species but I need sort of a nested matrix structure. But the problem is that each disease might have a different number of sub-forms...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, how about something like this:

```
# make a copy just in case
d = df[:]

# get the groups, in case you don't have them already
groups = list({col.split('_')[0] for col in d.columns})

# define grouping condition (here, groups would be 'xx', 'yy', 'kk')
gb = d.groupby(d.columns.map(lambda x: x.split('_')[0]), axis=1) 

# aggregate values of one group to list and save as extra columns
for g in groups:
   d[g] = gb.get_group(g).values.tolist()

# now aggregate to list of lists
d['matrix'] = d[groups].values.tolist()

# convert list of lists to a matrix
d['matrix'] = d['matrix'].apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame.from_records(x).fillna(0).astype(int).values)

# for the desired output
d[['matrix']]
```

Not the most elegant, but I'm hoping it does the job :)